# To return custom field in DjangoRestFramework after aggregation

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

There are lot of answers related to custom fields on stackoverflow but when trying with them, I am getting different error, so posting a separate question.

I wanted to return a JSON Response for the following url

**urls.py**

```
path('cards/<int:pk>/smarts', smarts.as_view(), name="smarts"),
```

I will be using below **api.py** file to return aggregate fields using **Transaction** model, the query is working fine, I only have to return appropriate response. Here I have one of the fields as Decimal hence tried with DjangoJSONEncoder but got an error.

**api.py**

```
class smarts(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TransactionIsOwnerOrNot]

    def get_queryset(self):
        card = get_object_or_404(self.request.user.cards, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        qs=card.transactions.values('vendor').annotate(a=Count('pk'),b=Sum('amount')).order_by('-b')
        ....CODE REQUIRED
        return ....
```

**models.py**

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Cards, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="transactions",null=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after hit and trial, I used custom serializer to return required field.

**serializer.py**

```
class SmartSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    vendor = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    tot = serializers.IntegerField()
    tot_amt = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

**api.py**

```
class smartstatements(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TransactionIsOwnerOrNot]
    serializer_class = SmartSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        card = get_object_or_404(self.request.user.cards, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        queryset=card.transactions.values('vendor')
                                      .annotate(tot=Count('pk'),tot_amt=Sum('amount'))
                                      .order_by('-tot_amt')
        return queryset
```